# How to create a stacked JavaFX Chart, with multiple Y Axis and common X Axis

Tags: javafx

Actually, I have exactly the same problem which was previously asked in the following link for D3. But I am searching a solution in JavaFx.

[How to create Stacked Line Chart D3, Multiple Y Axis and common X Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402112/how-to-create-stacked-line-chart-d3-multiple-y-axis-and-common-x-axis)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried. Adding a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) increases the changes of your question getting an answer.

Comment: post your code. i think your asking easy ? for me.if you post your i ll tell what is your mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VinceOPS thank you for answering but making the axis invisible cannot solve the problem since it will be used as common axis of a chart-set and at least one of the charts should display it.

This morning I've found an elegant solution for the common-axis-multichart problem.

If you use a common axis with multi-charts; at least one of the charts should display it where the others shouldn't.

The trick that I found is the following

```
// Inherit from XYChart and in c'tor remove the axis from chart-children.
public DoNotDisplayXAxisChartConstructor(Axis<Number> xAxis, Axis<Number> yAxis)
{
            super(xAxis, yAxis);
            getChartChildren().remove(xAxis); 
    // And now the chart can use the xAxis for layout but cannot display it.
}
```

It works...

Comment: "and at least one of the charts should display it".... Yes... That why I wrote in my answer "And then hide the X-axis OF THE FIRST ONE" ;-)... Anyway. Enjoy JavaFX.

Comment: But if you hide the axis of the first one, you will also hide the second one. Because we'll provide the same axis for both. "Common axis" is the keyword.
I mean the possibility of providing the same reference for all charts. If you delete this reference from the list of children, the chart can keep it as private but the list

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html) to vertically stack two Charts, and then hide the X-axis of the first one :

`// if chart.getXAxis().setVisible(false) doesn't do the trick:
chart.getXAxis().setTickLabelsVisible(false);
chart.getXAxis().setOpacity(0);`